# C++ recursion example explanation

Tags: c++, recursion

I have the following code example and I cannot figure out why it displays **123**.
Since these are integers I understand the decimals are not displayed. But I expected it to show **3**, **2**(.3), **1**(.23) (in the opposite order). When **n** goes below 10 everything stops after the final cout... right?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void recursion(int n)  {
    if (n < 10)  cout << n;
    else  {
        recursion(n / 10);
        cout << n % 10;
    }
}

int main()  {   
  recursion(123);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: step in with a debugger, and you'll see whats going on

Comment: I've never used a debugger :-)

Comment: Try moving the `cout << n % 10;` to before the recursive call... ;)

Comment: A tip for another debugging technique: Do it on paper!

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  I did and 321 :) But I still can't figure out why

Comment: Changing "cout << n" to "cout << n << endl" and "cout << n % 10" to "cout << n % 10 << endl" might help you understand what's going on. But as other said you shoud use debugger.

Comment: You just said "But I expected it to show 3, 2(.3), 1(.23) (in the opposite order)" and "I cannot figure out why it displays 123"... Changing "cout << n" to "cout << n << endl" and "cout << n % 10" to "cout << n % 10 << endl" might help you understand what's going on. But as other said you shoud use debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you call with 123 as `n`, the function executes the statement:

```
if (n < 10)      // its false, so it continues with else:  
else {
   recursion ( n /10 )  // recursive call n/10 = 123/10 = 12 (as it's int) 
...
```

It will continue like this, recursively calling with `n` being 12

```
    recursion (n/10)      // second recursion call n=12, so n/10 = 1
```

then the function is executed, with n being 1 so smaller than 10

```
        if (n < 10)      // its true 
            cout << n;   // 1 gets printed
        else             // no, the rest is skiped  
        ...
```

then it returns from recursion.  So we're back in the context where `n` was 12. The next statement to be executed in that context is :

```
    cout << n %10;    //  prints 12 % 10, which is 2
```

then, continuing like this, similarly it will print 123%10, which is 3. In conclusion, the 123 that is printed has nothing to do with the 123 entered as input.

I think you wanted to do :

```
...
else  {
    cout << n % 10;       // first print to see the count down
    recursion(n / 10);    // then recurse 
}
```

But you have to learn using a debugger. As long as you don't, put some extra `cout` to visualize what's happening.

Comment: Hmm ok! So when n = 123 reaches `recursion(123 / 10)`, the program won't forget about n = 123. It will simply just try to satisfy the IF statement by dividing down numbers before it finally can start `cout << n % 10` statements for each dividing result.. ? (If that question makes any sense. If it doesn't, thanks for the help, things are a bit clearer now!)

Comment: Yes ! That's it.  At each recursion, the function is executed again, but with its own parameters and local variables.  This is done with stack memory.  When the function returns, all its local context is removed from stack, and the context of the calling function is restored to the state before the call  (if parameters are passed by value).

Comment: Here a link with some additional explanations (and a nice graphic of recursive exececution):  http://sourcecodemania.com/recursion-in-cpp/